# Can I interact with a button created by a loop from a different class?

Tags: java, user-interface

The two methods listed below are from two separate classes, one that builds a GUI and the other that handles the game logic (as per request). My question is am I able to interact with the buttons created in the for loop from the other class?

```
public void colorChange()
{
    if (play() == true){
        button.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    else {
        button.setBackground(Color.black);
    }
}

public JPanel makeInnerJPanel()
{
    JPanel inner = new JPanel((new GridLayout(5, 5)));
    String[] items = new String[] {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",
            "","","","","","",""};
    for (int i = 0; i<items.length; i++){
        JButton button = new JButton(items[i]);
        button.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                }
            }
        );
        inner.add(button);
    }

    return inner;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying if you can call `colorChange()` from `actionPerformed()`? Have you tried it? What happens?

Answer (score 0):

You could make the variables public

```
public JButton[] button;
```

access them from another class

```
CLASSNAME.button;
```